# Accessing a piece of data quickly from a very large sharedObject-data

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I'm caching really big amount of data on the users hard-drive using sharedObject, this data can be like 0.5GB. But I don't want to place the whole sharedObject in memory, and the data also needs to be accessed very fast. Should I split the data up into multiple sharedObjects, or do you think it wouldn't be a problem loading the whole thing in and letting it be garbage-collected each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to think that multiple shared objects would be the best way to go, but I don't know what your performance requirements are.  I'm not inclined to think that the garbage collection would be an issue -- it doesn't seem like it could be any worse than loading the whole 0.5gb at once.  Ultimately, your best bet here is going to be to experiment.